# `tcpdump bootp.type == 2` tcpdump: syntax error

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, tcpdump

`tcpdump -i eth0 'bootp.type == 2'`

Results in a:

> tcpdump: syntax error

However, `bootp.type == 2` works fine in Wireshark.

Also `tcpdump -i eth0 'tcp[13] & 16!=0'` works fine, no syntax error.

update: I am attempting to follow the answer here https://serverfault.com/a/8534/101677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, it isn't possible. `bootp.type` filter is only for Wireshark & TShark. I need to use TShark for the `bootp.type` filter. This works for me:

`tshark -i eth0 -Y 'bootp.type == 2'`

Here are the options explained from `man tshark`:

> `-i  <capture interface>`
>
> `-Y  <displaY filter>`

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/304715/101677

Update: The `-Y <display filter>` option is available on at least tshark 1.10.6, some servers may have an older version like 1.8.10 which don't support that filter. If you cannot or don't want to install a new version then use the `-R <read (display) filter>`.